# Center submenu items with a variable width

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to center the submenu under the menu item, but I seem to have it a roadblock. Here's a working example of where I'm at now: http://jsfiddle.net/zCWXb/

Since the submenu has a variable width, I can't seem to understand how you would position it in the center relative to the parent menu item.

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Menu Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu Item 2</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item Long Name Example 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu Item 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
/*
    NAV
*/
body {
    background: #000;
}

.menu {
    position: absolute;
    left: 40px;
    top: 20px;
    color: #d6dcbd;
    font-family: 'nevis', Arial, "Arial Black", "Arial Bold", Gadget, sans-serif;
}
.menu .sub-menu {
    text-align: center;
    display:none;
    padding-top: 4px;
    width: auto;
    z-index: 20;
    position: absolute;
    left: -6px;
}
.menu .sub-menu li {
    text-align: center;
    background: #a9d6e4;
    display: block;
    float: none;
    width: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 4px 6px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;

    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.menu .sub-menu li a {
    color: #121212;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.menu .sub-menu li:hover {
    color: #FFF;
    background: #d6dcbd;
}
#menu-default > li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

.menu li {
    width: auto;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 25px 0 0;
}
.menu a {
    font-family: 'nevis', Arial, "Arial Black", "Arial Bold", Gadget, sans-serif;
    color: #d6dcbd;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.menu a:hover {
    color: #FFF;
}

.menu .current-menu-item a {
    color: #FFF;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.menu li').hover(
        //Mouseover, fadeIn the hidden hover class 
        function() {
            $(this).children('.sub-menu').stop(true, true).fadeIn('1000');   
        },
        //Mouseout, fadeOut the hover class
        function() {
            $(this).children('.sub-menu').stop(true, true).fadeOut('1000');  
    })
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('.menu li').hover(
        //Mouseover, fadeIn the hidden hover class 
        function() {
            var $this = $(this),
                $subMenu = $this.children('.sub-menu')
            $subMenu.stop(true, true).fadeIn('1000')
            .css("left", -1*($subMenu.width()/2) + $this.width()/2)         

        },
        //Mouseout, fadeOut the hover class
        function() {
            $(this).children('.sub-menu').stop(true, true).fadeOut('1000');  
})​;
```

Working demo - http://jsfiddle.net/zCWXb/8/

Comment: I ended up using yours. Thank you so much. Makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

I just updated your jsfiddle here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/zCWXb/10/

Answer (score 0):

Try and update the following rule:

```css
.menu .sub-menu {
    /* ... */
    left: -25%;
    margin-left: -50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/4Xwwv/

Just my method. The one extra thing you are going to have to consider here is what if the parent element is all the way to the left of the page and there is a centered long sub menu element. The element would go off the left of the browser.